Finding independent copies of converging random variables
Suppose that $X_i \sim X_j$ and independent. Morever suppose there exists $X_{n,i} \rightarrow X_i$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ a.s and $\mathrm{supp}(X_{n,i}) \subset \mathrm{supp} X_i$ a.s. Does there exists $X_{n,j}\rightarrow X_j$ such that $X_{n,j}\sim X_{n,i}$ a.s. and $\mathrm{supp}(X_{n,j}) \subset \mathrm{supp} X_j$ a.s.?
I came off with this problem myself, so I don't know if it is true or not. I assume that $X_i$ and $X_j$ are on the same probability space. So the Skorohod representation theorem does not seem to help. I want $(X_{n,i})$ and $(X_{n,j})$ to be on the same probability spaces. I was wondering if there are results that can help to conclude this. Thanks.
